# Як правильно бажати людині одужання?

Tags: росіянізм, словосполучення

Я постійно ловлю себе на думці, що в мене немає короткого й влучного виразу, яким я міг би поспівчувати людині що хворіє. Російською можна сказати *"выздоравливай"*, мною воно сприймається як досить неформальне й не надто помпезне. Українською одразу згадується "бажаю найшвидшого одужання", але хотілося б вжити коротший та менш формальний вислів.

Чи правильно казати **"одужуй"**? Мені ця форма чомусь звучить як калька з російської

Які є усталені слова для висловлення співчуття друзям, яким не пощастило захворіти?

Comment: Бажаю вам здоров'я і якнайшвидшого одужання

Answer (score 3):

Не маю нічого проти інших варіантів, але й не бачу абсолютно нічого поганого в слові *одужуй*:

> Одужуй, брат, скоріше; гулять підемо до річки, а то і я вже занудився, сидячи в хаті (Панас Мирний, «Лихі люди», 1875).

> Одужуй скоріше.
> <…>
> Ну, одужуй скоріше.
> <…>
> Одужуй скоріше, — і, прощаючись, ласкаво торкається пальцями до розбухлої руки Горицвіта (Михайло Стельмах, «Велика рідня», 1951).

> Сам знаю, що воно за гидота — оці всякі хвороби, та ще й у молодому, сказати[,] віці! Одужуйте! Привіт дружині й «хрещениці» (З листів Максима Рильського, 1958).